# dyld: library not loaded: AlamofireObjectMapper Reason: image not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, alamofireobjectmapper

I have added into my react native app's podfile a pod (NewPod) which has dependecy to AlamofireObjectMapper. I am trying to run my project and I get the error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AlamofireObjectMapper.framework/AlamofireObjectMapper
>     Referenced from: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/74176933-8DFE-4A36-AA0C-9E7AC01EF038/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/031D8C1A-6B3D-418C-8728-91B0852DA637/XXX.app/Frameworks/NewPod.framework/NewPod
>     Reason: image not found

I tried to add into my linked Binary and Libraries the framework but it is not available, I can only find libAlamofireObjectMapper.a which is not enough. Error remains. I am using xcode 11.3.1

Any thoughts?

Comment: NewPod is a swift library and my code is obj C, in case it is an important information

Answer (score 0):

use_frameworks! into my pod file saved the day. I found some other errors of course but they were easy to get solved.